# Internal server error 500 after 90 seconds of PHP script running

Tags: php, iis, timeout

have a php script that runs for a few minutes. It creates a lot (up to 10000) of small (2-20K) files on the server.

For some reason, after approximately 90 seconds, I always get a 500 Internal Server Error. I thought it might be some php.ini problem, so I edited some values there:

```
max_execution_time = 1000
max_input_time = 1000
default_socket_timeout = 1000
memory_limit = 400M
post_max_size = 100M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

I also checked to see if these new settings occurred by using phpinfo(), and have seen that they did take effect.

What else can I do/change in order to make my script work?

PHP5.5
Windows Server 2008 R2, SP1, 
Unfortunately, only 600 MB of physical memory 
Nothing in errors_log.

Comment: CLI or CGI? if using php-fpm, you should also change time limit in php-fpm.conf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In hope to save other people's hair (I pulled out pretty much of my own on this one)

The solution is to increase the FastCGI activity timeout.
Use **appcmd**, the IIS 7 command line tool, to modify the IIS configuration XML file.

Run **cmd** in an administrator mode.

To check the current settings use:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi
```

To add the activity timeout (assuming CGI location is C:\php\php-cgi.exe):

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /[fullPath='C:\php\php-cgi.exe'].activityTimeout:600
```

This output now should be similar to this: -

```
<system.webServer>
<fastCgi>
<application fullPath="C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe" activityTimeout="600" instanceMaxRequests="10000">
<environmentVariables>
<environmentVariable name="PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" value="10000" />
</environmentVariables>
</application>
</fastCgi>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 3):

The command in the answer post did not work for me.

This is the correct one:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi "-[fullPath='C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.2\php-cgi.exe'].activityTimeout:3600"
```

Note the double quotes.
Credits to http://www.bokko.nl/increase-fastcgi-php-activitytimeout-in-iis7/